# Find difference between each element in flat array fast

Tags: python

If I have 2 arrays like a = 1x2 array and b = 1x3 array,
is there then a fast way to find the difference between each entry individually such that the output would be like so:

```
output = [[a[0]-b[0], a[0]-b[1], a[0]-b[2]]
           a[1]-b[0], a[1]-b[1], a[1]-b[2]]]
```

example

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 1, 2]
output = [[0, 0, -1] [1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Are you using *Numpy* array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
output = np.subtract(np.array(a)[:, np.newaxis], b)
```

It was rightfully pointed out that this equivalent to

```
import numpy as np
output = np.array(a)[:, None] - b
```

`output` is then a numpy array with shape (2,3):

```
array([[ 0,  0, -1],
       [ 1,  1,  0]])
```

Comment: `a[:,None]-b` gives the same results

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehensions

```py
[[i - j for j in b] for i in a]
```

read more here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

[(nested) list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is useful to simplify loops into a few lines.

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 1, 2]
output = [[x - y for y in b] for x in a]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use nested list comprehension for list output

```
result=[[itemA - itemB for itemB in b] for itemA in a]
```

or for np.ndarray output

```
result=np.subtract(a[:, None], b)
```